# Floor Function Bound?

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to prove or disprove the following bound:

$2+\left(n-\left\lfloor\dfrac n k\right\rfloor k\right)\ge \left\lfloor\dfrac n k\right\rfloor$, where $2<k\le \left\lfloor\dfrac {n-1} 2\right\rfloor$, $n>4$, $k, n$ are coprime, and $n,k\in\mathbb N$.

Any suggestions, solutions, or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Coprime doesn't really matter.  The point is to see that as $n$ increases, the right side increases without bound, while the left is bounded.

Comment: Perhaps a better question then would be: under what conditions would this inequality hold?

Comment: If $n=2k+1$, which is the minimum, the right side will be $2$ and the left will be $3$.  The left is $2+(n\pmod k)$, so if $n=3k-1$ the left will grow with $k$ and the right will stay $2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true.  Take $n$ huge.  The left side is no greater than $k+1$, the right is unbounded in $n$.  For a specific, $n=101, k=3$, we are comparing $2+(101-33\cdot 3)=4$ and $\lfloor \frac {101}3 \rfloor =33$

Comment: $k$ has to be greater than 2.

Comment: Ok, but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n=16$, $k=3$ and $n=7$, $k=3$. The first case yields $<$, the second one yields $>$.

Comment: Neither of these work with the conditions on k.

Comment: @user2154420 edited them to reflect your new conditions.