# Quick floor function

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This isn't true, right?

$$k\left\lfloor\frac n {2k}\right\rfloor\leq \left\lfloor\frac n k\right\rfloor$$

$2<k\leq \left\lfloor\dfrac {n-1} 2\right\rfloor$, $n>4$, $k,n$ are coprime.

Comment: Those $k$ and $n$ do not meet the conditions provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853660/floor-function-bound) one check is what happens at the numbers grow.  If $k$ is as large as possible (for a given $n$) the right side will be $2$.  The left side will be about $\frac n2$, which can be large.  Take, for example, $n=101,k=50$.  Then the left is $50$, the right is $2$.  Often it helps just to ignore the floor function for a preliminary investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=15$ and $k=4$. Not that $15>4$, $2<4<\left\lfloor\dfrac{15-1}{2}\right\rfloor=7$, and that $gcd(4,15)=1$

Now

$$k\left\lfloor\dfrac {2n} k\right\rfloor=4\left\lfloor\dfrac {30} 4\right\rfloor=28$$

and

$$\left\lfloor\dfrac n k\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\dfrac {15}4\right\rfloor=3$$

Clearly $28>3$, so this provides a counterexample.

Comment: SHOOT! I meant to put the 2 in the denominator, sorry!